# How to add item to ObservableCollection, return from xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, deserialization, observablecollection

I'm getting data from xml file(local)

I have organized my model like below(this is a part of it)

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Availability")]
public class Availability
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Departure")]
    public List<Departure> departure { get; set; }
}


//availability ends here

[XmlRoot(ElementName="CruiseProduct")]
public class CruiseProduct
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Availability")]
    public Availability availability { get; set; }

}
```

**And this is my controller**

```
XElement cElement = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/CruiseData/cruiseprodutstwo.xml"));
var getdataa = cElement.Elements("CruiseProduct");


ObservableCollection<CruiseProduct> ResultantCollection = new ObservableCollection<CruiseProduct>();
foreach(var itmz in getdataa)
{
      ResultantCollection.Add(new CruiseProduct
      {

      });
}
```

How to add data to this? No idea. Is this the way or , is there a way to DeserializeObject lik json without usin ObservableCollection?

Comment: List<CruiseProduct> temp = new List<CruiseProduct>(); inside the loop and items in this temp list. finally out side of the loop add it to observable collection from observable collections constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like are wanting to deserialize xml from a file.
The following code should get you started.
[How to: Read Object Data from an XML File (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172872.aspx)

Making an assumption that your XML has some root node:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Root")]
public class Root
{
  public IEnumerable<CruiseProduct> CruiseProducts{ get; set; }
}

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
using (StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/CruiseData/cruiseprodutstwo.xml")))
{
  var data = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(file);
  var observablecruiseProducts = new ObservableCollection<CruiseProduct>(data.CruiseProducts);
}
```

Comment: this gives 
`Cannot serialize interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Kcruise.Models.CruiseProduct, Kcruise, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].`

this error